# Can I use the sentence for the thing I want to say

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

At the end of the video, people are called upon to sign a petition. Can I use the following sentence to describe this?

'Then there are some more printed words after which the video ends with a call to the viewer to sign a petition.'

Or do you have a better sentence?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing ungrammatical or unidiomatic about your proposed sentence.

But if you feel that the sentence is verbose and thus awkward, I agree.

> Then the video ends with another text, followed by a call to sign a petition.

I see no reason to say that the call is addressed to those viewing the video: to whom else could it possibly be addressed? If, however, you feel that your audience may be confused about those asked to sign, I'd say

> Then the video ends with another text, followed by a call for viewers to sign a petition.